# Locker Service Unable to use external scripts

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, locker-service

When using:

```
<ltng:require scripts="x,y,z" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.onScriptLoaded}/>
```

In a pre-release version of Spring '17 with Locker Service enabled, while in the controller method `onScriptLoaded`, I'm unable to use my external namespace. However, when I debug the included script, I clearly see that `window.MyCodeNamepsace` and `MyCodeNamepsace` evaluate to my code at the end of the included script `y`.
Why can't I access it using the `onScriptLoaded` method?

ps: it works flawlessly without Locker Service ;)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To reproduce this issue and investigate, can you provide us an unmanaged package or a git gist of your code? Reference doc to create an unmanaged package https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading_unmanaged.htm

Comment: I was able to get errors when I _don't_ use components inheritance. I am not able to share this code freely :(.

Comment: This is possibly because of a naming conflict. You can isolate the problem by using an elimination logic i.e, load x, y and z one at a time and see which one is actually causing the issue.

Comment: You can enable debugging for Lightning by doing this: Go to Setup page in your org, search for "Lightning Components", check "Enable Debug Mode" option and Save. It should be much more easier to break on exceptions using chrome developer tools and the error messages will be readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have checked your browser console log for errors :-)

Based on my experience, it's possible that your script is failing silently with LockerService activated. There is probably a method in your script that is behaving differently because of LockerService JS method override. My only recommendation would be to also debug your script and see where your code is failing. It's a tedious process, unfortunately.